# iOS Dropbox inconsistent (sometimes doesn't load)

Tags: ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have an app that connects to a user's Dropbox account and displays his files and folders. Most of the time it works, but sometimes the spinny-wheel spins forever or it says "Error loading data. Please try again." I'm wondering if there's some way I can fix this, or if it is just a problem on Dropbox's end. Here is the relevant code:

In AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
            NSLog(@"App linked successfully!");
            // At this point you can start making API calls
        }
        return YES;
    }
    // Add whatever other url handling code your app requires here
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//connect to Dropbox
    DBSession *dbSession = [[DBSession alloc]
                            initWithAppKey:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                            appSecret:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                            root:kDBRootDropbox]; // either kDBRootAppFolder or kDBRootDropbox
    [DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
return YES;
}
```

In DropboxViewController.m:

```
//this gets run when you load a Dropbox folder to see what's inside
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
    self.currentData = metadata;
    [folderView reloadData];

    //stop activity indicator
    [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    [self.activityIndicatorView removeFromSuperview];
}

//this gets run if there's an error loading the folder
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadMetadataFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {
    //show alert
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Error loading data. Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //prepare activity indicator
    self.activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.view.center;
    self.activityIndicatorView.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicatorView];
    [self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    //fix glitch of extra space above first cell
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

    //login to Dropbox, if not already
    if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
    }

    self.restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
    self.restClient.delegate = self;

    //load folders
    [self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];

    //display the title at the top
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Dropbox";
}

//rest client delegate methods
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedFile:(NSString *)localPath
       contentType:(NSString *)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {

    //stop activity indicator
    [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    [self.activityIndicatorView removeFromSuperview];

    //load the file preview and push onto the nav controller
    QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    previewController.dataSource = self;
    previewController.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0;
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadFileFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"There was an error loading the file: %@", error];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: The "Error loading data" message is coming from your code in `loadMetadataFailedWithError`. The `loadMetadataFailedWithError` method is supplied an `NSError` in `error` that you can inspect to see what the underlying issue is.